# Composition and Commutators of Fourier Multiplier Operators

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, operator-theory

I am working with some Fourier multiplier operators arising in study of a PDE. I have a general question: Suppose $S$ and $T$ be two Fourier multiplier operators (on some space) with multipliers $m_1$ and $m_2$. Is it true that composition $ST$ will also be a Fourier multiplier operator with multiplier $m_1m_2$? If $S$ is invertible then is it true that $S^{-1}$ is also a Fourier multiplier operator with multiplier ${m_1}^{-1}$? What about the commutator $ST-TS$?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can write $S = \mathcal F^{-1} \circ \mathcal M \circ \mathcal F$, where $\mathcal F$ is the Fourier transform, and $\mathcal M$ is multiplication by $m_1$.  Go from there.

Answer (score 0):

Write $$Su(x)=\mathcal{F}^{-1}( m_1(\xi)\mathcal{F}u(\xi))(x),$$ and $$Tu(x)=\mathcal{F}^{-1}( m_2(\xi)\mathcal{F}u(\xi))(x).$$ It's easy to check that

\begin{align*}(T\circ S)u(x)&=\mathcal{F}^{-1}( m_2(\xi)\mathcal{F}(Su)(\xi))(x)\\
&=\mathcal{F}^{-1}( m_2(\xi)m_1(\xi)\mathcal{F}u(\xi))(x)\\
&=\mathcal{F}^{-1}( m_1(\xi)m_2(\xi)\mathcal{F}u(\xi))(x)\\
&=(S\circ T)u(x).\end{align*} Hence, $[S,T]=0,$ and the symbol of $S\circ T=T\circ S$ is $m_1m_2=m_2m_1.$

Next, let $T$ be the Fourier multiplier with symbol $1/m_1,$ where we assume that $m_1$ is non-vanishing. Since $m_1 (1/m_1)=1,$ it follows the composition of $T$ and $S$ is simply $\mathcal{F}^{-1} \mathcal{F}=I.$ So, $T=S^{-1}$. This can also be seem from inverting the composition $$S=\mathcal{F}^{-1} \circ m_1\circ\mathcal{F},$$ to get $$S^{-1}= \mathcal{F}^{-1} \circ (1/m_1)\circ\mathcal{F}.$$  Note that we are inverting the multiplication operator, which is why we divide by $m_1,$ not apply its inverse.